# zone has no NS records

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a bind zone with an entry:

```
ns  NS              localhost.
```

this gives the error: "zone has no NS records"

changing it to the following solves the error.

```
@   NS              localhost.
```

Can somebody explain why the first option isn't a valid NS record?

Comment: It would be nice to see the line with SOA records and part from main config. '@' inherits domain name, so you either have it correctly written in SOA line or defined in main config.

Answer (score 1):

If your input file includes something like this:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
```

Then:

```
@ NS localhost.
```

Is equivalent to:

```
example.com. ns localhost.
```

Whereas:

```
ns NS localhost.
```

Is equivalent to:

```
ns.example.com. NS localhost.
```

In the first example, using `@`, you are specifying an `NS` record for the domain `example.com`.  In the second example, you are specifying an `NS` record for the domain `ns.example.com`.  So you're getting that error because the domain you've told BIND about -- `example.com` -- does not have any nameserver records.